# How do I filter a model field case insensitive and unaccent?

Tags: django

I need to make a query that return results ignoring case and accents.
Example: I search for 'atacadao' and as a possible answer would be Atacadão, atacadão, Atacadao and atacadao.

Comment: you can use `__icontains=` to ignoring case

Comment: You need to use some collation which is case insensitive and accent insensitive. The name of the collation you can use depends on the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe native python will do this.  You will need to use a library to decode the text first, and then search against the database.

A popular one is Unidecode which is explained in this article:

[What is the best way to remove accents (normalize) in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string)